# Rails 3.2: Why does will_paginate page link disapear after first click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, will-paginate

I'm trying to implement jQuery Ajax into my rails app and so far it's working, but there is a bug I am unable wrap my head around. Basically, I have a books page which lists all books using will_paginate to group them in pages of 5 each.

My index.html.erb file for Books view has this snippet of code:

```
<div id="page_paginate">
    <%= will_paginate @books %><br />
    <%= render @books %>

 </div>
```

the @books partial is saved as _book.html.erb and looks like this:

```
<div class="books_box">
 <h1><%= book.title%><span>(<%=link_to book.author.name, book.author%>)</span></h1>
  <img alt="image" src="<%= book.image_url %>">
    <div class="book_info">
         <div class="detail_button"><%= link_to "Details", '#' %></div>
         <div class="like_button"><%= link_to "Like", '#' %></div>                 
    </div
```

In my application.js file, I have the following code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#page_paginate .pagination a").live("click", function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });

});
```

And I also have an index.js.erb file in the views/books directory:

```
$("#page_paginate").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@books))%>")
```

The issue is:

While the pagination works perfectly with ajax; pages turn without page reloading and all, the pagination links disappear after the first click nd I have to go back to the books_url to get it to show again. I have tried putting the <%= will_paginate %> in the books partial this way:

```
<%= will_paginate @books %><br />
<div class="books_box">
     <h1><%= book.title%><span>(<%=link_to book.author.name, book.author%>)</span></h1>
      <img alt="image" src="<%= book.image_url %>">
        <div class="book_info">
             <div class="detail_button"><%= link_to "Details", '#' %></div>
             <div class="like_button"><%= link_to "Like", '#' %></div>                 
        </div

  </div>
```

but that way, the page links show on top of every listing. My aim is to have the pagination links show only above and below the the end of every page. I figure it's probably a problem with my loops or where I place the links but I have tried everything my novice mind could possibly conceive. I would appreciate a little help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the following code runs

```
$("#page_paginate").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@books))%>")
```

it effectively removes everything within `<div id="page_paginate">`:

```
<div id="page_paginate">
    <%= will_paginate @books %><br /> <!-- This is removed. -->
    <%= render @books %> <!-- This is also removed. -->
</div>
```

before it applies `.html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@books))%>")`.

To prevent `<%= will_paginate @books %><br />` from being removed, wrap `<%= render @books %>` in another `<div>` as follows:

```
<div id="page_paginate">
    <%= will_paginate @books %><br />
    <div id="books_render">
        <%= render @books %>
    </div>
</div>
```

and select `#books_render` instead of `#page_paginate` in `index.js.erb`:

```
$("#books_render").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@books))%>")
```

Comment: I'm sorry to be a bother, but for future reference, why is it necessary to escape javascript on the  page_paginate div in the ifrst place?

Comment: But this won't update pagination elements. In first page if you have 2 pages, even if you get 1 page after the call it will still show 2 pages. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @GokhanArik I am unable to tell what the context of your question is, perhaps it will be better to open a new question.